# Usuario no se inserta a pesar que la validación es correcta

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Tengo un problema extraño, la validación de que el usuario se inserto si corre pero el usuario no se inserta en la base de datos

Esto es lo que tengo en caddusuario.php, solamente contiene lo que el usuario puede ver

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
header('location:login.php'); 
}
require_once '../models/usuarioModel.php';
$usuario = new usuarioModel();
$cargos = $usuario->getCargo();

require_once '../models/paisesModel.php';  
$paises = new paisesModel();
$paisesList = $paises->getpaisesList();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" ng-app> 
    <head>
        <!--  Require Gobal -->
        <?php require("../require/head.require.php"); ?> 
        <!-- CSS -->
        <?php require("../require/css.require.php"); ?>
        <?php require("../require/insidecss.require.php"); ?> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--  Require Variables -->
        <?php require("../require/get.require.php"); ?>
        <?php require("../require/function.require.php"); ?>
        
        <!--  GLobal -->
        <div class="page-wrap">
          <!--  Menu -->
          <?php require("../require/menu.require.php"); ?>

          <div class="container-fluid padding-container">            
            <!-- Breadcrumb -->
            <?php require("../require/breadcrumb.php"); ?>

            <!-- Border General -->
            <div class="border-1-oscuro padding-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <form class="formPaddign" id="formCaddusuario">
                        <div class="row">

                            <!-- Datos Personales -->

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-indi-seccion">
                                   Datos Personales
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>No. identidad <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Cedula" id="Cedula" required autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                            </div>                            

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Primer nombre <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Primer_nombre" required autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Segundo nombre</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Segundo_nombre" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Primer apellido <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Primer_apellido" required autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Segundo apellido</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Segundo_apellido" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Sexo <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label style="padding-right: 30px;">
                                            <input type="radio" id="Mujer" name="Id_sexo" value="2"  required> Mujer
                                        </label>
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="Hombre" name="Id_sexo" value="1"  required> Hombre
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="Id_sexo" class="error"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Fecha de nacimiento <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="input-group date" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Fecha_nacimiento" id="Fecha_nacimiento" placeholder="Seleccione una fecha de nacimiento" autocomplete="off" required="required" />
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="Fecha_nacimiento" class="error"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Datos Contacto -->

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-indi-seccion" style="margin-top: 30px">
                                    Datos de contacto
                                </div>
                            </div>                            
                            

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Dirección <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <textarea name="Direccion" id="Direccion" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Número teléfonico</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Telefono" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Número móvil <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Movil" autocomplete="off" required="required" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>eMail <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email_principal" id="Email_principal"required autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>eMail secundario</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email_secundario" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nombre de Usuario</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Usuario" id="Usuario" autocomplete="off" readonly="">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Contraseña <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" id="Password" required autocomplete="off">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--  Datos administrativos -->

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-indi-seccion" style="margin-top: 30px">
                                    Datos administrativos
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>País <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" id="Id_pais" name="Id_pais" required onchange="seleccionarCiudadPais()">   
                                        <option value="" selected style="display: none;" >Seleccione un pais</option>
                                        <?php foreach($paisesList as $resultadoPais):?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $resultadoPais['id_pais']?>"><?php echo $resultadoPais['nombre_pais']?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Ciudad <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" name="Id_ciudad" id="Id_ciudad" required="required" onchange="seleccionarZonaCiudad()">
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" value="" >Seleccionar ciudad</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Zona <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" name="Id_zona" id="Id_zona" required="required" onchange="seleccionarCentro('Zona')">
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" value="">Seleccionar zona</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Centro <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" name="Id_centro" id="Id_centro" required="required">
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" value="">Seleccionar centro</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Cargo <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" name="Id_acceso" id="Id_acceso" required>
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" value="">Selecciona algun Cargo</option>
                                        <?php foreach($cargos as $tipoCargo):?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $tipoCargo['id_acceso']?>"><?php echo $tipoCargo['descripcion']?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="col-md-12 col-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-verde" id="addUser" name="addUser">Añadir</button>
                            </div>    
                        
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>                
            </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>

        </div>

        <!--  Footer -->
        <?php require("../require/footer.require.php"); ?>
        
        <!-- JS -->
        <?php require("../require/js.require.php"); ?>
        <?php require("../require/insidejs.require.php"); ?>

        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript">

           $('#Fecha_nacimiento').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ 
                weekStart : 0, 
                time: false,
                format : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                currentDate : moment("1980 01 01", "YYYY MM DD")
            });

            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#Email_principal").keyup(function (){
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    $("#Usuario").val(value);
                });
            });
               
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Al presionar addUser, main.js llama a un controlador por AJAX

```
jQuery(document).on("submit", "#formCaddusuario", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  datos = $(this).serializeArray();
  datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "addUser" });
  jQuery
    .ajax({
      url: "../controllers/usuarioController.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: datos,
    })
    .done(function (data) {
      var success = JSON.parse(data).success;
      var msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
      if (success) {
        swal("¡Realizado!", msj, "success").then((value) => {
          $("#formCaddusuario")[0].reset();
          $("#Cedula").focus();
        });
      } else {
        swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
      }
    });
});
```

En usuariocontroller.php, detecta la opcion y la dirigue a una funcion

```
    if($opcion == 'addUser'){

        foreach ($_POST as $nombre => $valor) {

            $datos[$nombre] = htmlentities($valor);

            $datos[$nombre] = html_entity_decode($datos[$nombre]);

        }

        self::añadirUsuario($datos);

    }

public function añadirUsuario($datos){

    $usuario = new usuarioModel;

    $json = array();

    $Cedula = $datos['Cedula'];

    $Primer_nombre = $datos['Primer_nombre'];

    $Primer_apellido = $datos['Primer_apellido'];

    $Id_sexo = $datos['Id_sexo'];

    $Email_principal = $datos['Email_principal'];

    $Usuario = $datos['Usuario'];

    $Password = $datos['Password'];


    if($Cedula == ''){ $json['msj'] = 'Error . Campo cedula vacia'; $json['success'] = false; echo json_encode($json); }

    if($Primer_nombre == ''){ $json['msj'] = 'Error . Campo Primer Nombre vacio'; $json['success'] = false; echo json_encode($json); }

    if($Primer_apellido == ''){ $json['msj'] = 'Error . Campo Primer Apellido vacio'; $json['success'] = false; echo json_encode($json); }

    if($Id_sexo == ''){ $json['msj'] = 'Error . Campo de sexo vacio'; $json['success'] = false; echo json_encode($json); }

    if($Email_principal == ''){ $json['msj'] = 'Error . Campo de email vacio'; $json['success'] = false; echo json_encode($json); }

    if($Usuario == ''){ $json['msj'] = 'Error . Campo de nombre de usaurio vacio'; $json['success'] = false; echo json_encode($json); }

    if($Password == ''){ $json['msj'] = 'Error . Campo de contraseña vacio'; $json['success'] = false; echo json_encode($json); }

    

    if($usuario->getInfoUsuarios($datos) != true){

        if($usuario->addUsuario($datos) == true){

        $json['msj'] = 'El usuario se añadio exitosamente'; 
        $json['success'] = true;
        echo json_encode($json);
        }

    }else{

        $json['msj'] = 'Error . No se pudo realizar la consulta email principal o cedula ya esta registrado'; 
        $json['success'] = false;
        echo json_encode($json);

    }


}
```

Mi problema, es que addUsuario en el modal, no inserta el usuario y cree que lo inserto pero no lo hizo. Aqui dejo el código del método, el cual esta en UsuarioModel.php

```
public  function addUsuario($datos){

    require '../require/Conexion.php';

    $Cedula = $datos['Cedula'];
    $Primer_nombre = $datos['Primer_nombre'];
    $Primer_nombre = addslashes($Primer_nombre);
    $Segundo_nombre = $datos['Segundo_nombre'];
    $Segundo_nombre = addslashes($Segundo_nombre);
    $Primer_apellido = $datos['Primer_apellido'];
    $Primer_apellido = addslashes($Primer_apellido);
    $Segundo_apellido = $datos['Segundo_apellido'];
    $Segundo_apellido = addslashes($Segundo_apellido);
    $Id_sexo = $datos['Id_sexo'];
    $Id_estatus = 1;
    $originalFecha = date($datos['Fecha_nacimiento']);
    $Fecha_nacimiento = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $originalFecha);
    $Fecha_nacimiento = $Fecha_nacimiento->format('Y-m-d');
    $Id_pais = $datos['Id_pais']; 
    $Id_ciudad = $datos['Id_ciudad'];
    $Id_zona = $datos['Id_zona'];
    $Id_centro = $datos['Id_centro'] ;
    $Direccion = $datos['Direccion'];
    $Direccion = addslashes($Direccion); 
    $Telefono = $datos['Telefono'];
    $Movil = $datos['Movil'];
    $Email_principal = strtolower($datos['Email_principal']);
    $Email_secundario = $datos['Email_secundario'];
    $Usuario = strtolower($datos['Usuario']);
    $Usuario =  md5($Usuario);
    $Password = md5 ($datos['Password']);
    $Id_acceso = $datos['Id_acceso'] ;
    $Fecha_registro = date("Y/m/d");
    $result = array();
    $sql = array();

    
    array_push($sql,"INSERT INTO `ec_usuario` (`id_sexo`,`id_acceso`, `id_estatus`, `primer_nombre`, `segundo_nombre`, `primer_apellido`, `segundo_apellido`, `cedula`, `fecha_nacimiento`, `usuario`, `password`, `fecha_registro`) VALUES ('".$Id_sexo."','".$Id_acceso."' , '".$Id_estatus."', '".$Primer_nombre."', '".$Segundo_nombre."', '".$Primer_apellido."', '".$Segundo_apellido."', '".$Cedula."', '".$Fecha_nacimiento."', '".$Usuario."', '".$Password."', '".$Fecha_registro."');");




    

    array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql[0]));

    $Id_usuario = $mysqli->insert_id;

    array_push($sql,"INSERT INTO `ec_direccion_usuario` (`id_usuario`, `id_pais`, `id_ciudad`, `id_zona`, `id_centro`, `direccion`) VALUES ('".$Id_usuario."', '".$Id_pais."', '".$Id_ciudad."', '".$Id_zona."', '".$Id_centro."', '".$Direccion."');");

    array_push($sql,"INSERT INTO `ec_telefonos_usuario` (`id_tipotelefono`, `id_usuario`, `numero_telefono`) VALUES ('1', '".$Id_usuario."', '".$Telefono."'), ('2', '".$Id_usuario."', '".$Movil."'), ('3', '".$Id_usuario."', 0);");

    array_push($sql,"INSERT INTO `ec_email_usuario` (`id_tipoemail`, `id_usuario`, `direccion_email`) VALUES ('1', '".$Id_usuario."', '".$Email_principal."'), ('2', '".$Id_usuario."', '".$Email_secundario."');");
    
    array_push($sql,"INSERT INTO `ec_contacto_emergencia` (`id_usuario`, `nombre_emergencia`, `relacion`, `email_emergencia`, `telefono_emergencia`) VALUES ('".$Id_usuario."', '', '', '', '');");

    array_push($sql,"INSERT INTO `ec_alerta` (`id_usuario`, `id_tipoalerta`, `descripcion`) VALUES ('".$Id_usuario."', '1', ''), ('".$Id_usuario."', '2', '');");
    
    array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql[1]));
    array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql[2]));
    array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql[3]));
    array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql[4]));
    array_push($result, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql[5]));
    

    

    if($result == true){

        return $result;

    }else{

        return $sql;


    }
 
}
```

Comment: **Advertencia:** En PHP 7, llamar a métodos no estáticos de forma estática está obsoleto y generará una advertencia E_DEPRECATED. El soporte para las llamadas a métodos no estáticos de forma estática podría ser eliminado en el futuro. Referencia: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: El comentario anterior es en referencia a `self::añadirUsuario($datos);` donde realizas una llamada estática a una función no-estática: `public function añadirUsuario($datos) { ... }` y desde ahí pueden comenzar los problemas.

Comment: Intente volverla estatica y no funciono igualmente

Comment: Deja la función solo como _public_, no estática, cambia la llamada a `$this->añadirUsuario($datos);` y, en _Javascript_ antes de convertir a JSON, coloca `console.log(data);` para ver lo que aparece en consola. También revisa la petición, en la pestaña "Respuesta" y edita la pregunta para agregar lo que estás recibiendo.

Comment: Un INSERT puede fallar por error de sintaxis, puede fallar también en el caso de violar una restricción (datos duplicados, filas huérfanas en un contexto de integridad referencial, etc). En tu código no veo que se controlen esos posibles fallos en el INSERT. En código demasiado ingenuo que deberías robustecer previendo todo aquello que podría salir mal y controlando el flujo del mismo en esos casos.

Comment: Esos errores se controlan en donde dice getInfoUsuarios en usuariocontroller, ese if si detecta si hay un repetido, el problema es que el INSERT no corre

Comment: ¿Ya verificaste que el programa "entra" a y "sale correctamente" de los métodos invocados? las validaciones con **$algo == ''** devuelven true cuando $algo = 0 entre otros. Adicionalmente, la asignación **$datos[$nombre] = valor_a_asignar** se hace sin verificar que todos los campos esperados hayan llegado. Los radios y ciertas opciones pueden no venir (**pasar valores**). De modo que cuando tratas de asignar $variable = $dato['clave_que_puede_no_estar']; el método debe interrumpirse.

Comment: Eh, dicen algo los logs de PHP? yo pondría la inserción dentro de un try para ver qué pasa...

Comment: ¿Ya miraste en el head que datos está mandando a ver si hay campos nulos?.

Comment: Para mi es bastante obvio que no funcione: En tu llamada ajax solo pasas   `datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "addUser" });` y no le pasas los datos del formulario ¿Como esperas que lleguen a php? Ni siquiera muestras que hay en el log de php, lo cual me dice que ni siquiera sabes si llegan los valores del formulario a php.

Comment: @abrahamhs pareciera que `datos = $(this).serializeArray();` se encargaría de agregar los campos el form con el push adicionando un campo extra, ( yo usaría `URLSearchParams` + `FormData` para hacer un append de data extra pero para gustos colores ), veo mas preocupante el uso de un `@` para llamar a `mysqli_query` que suprimiría todos los errores si hubiera

Comment: Tambien deberias considerar usar una funcion hash mas segura. MD5 se dejo de usar de esa forma hace ya un tiempo debido a que fueron encontradas colisiones y otras debilidades criptograficas. Una buena alternativa es SHA-256 o SHA-512.